# What punctuation is this sentence missing?

Tags: punctuation

> One big ass mistake America.

I'm thinking it should be:

> One big ass mistake, America.

Comment: One big ass-mistake America.  Source: http://xkcd.com/37/

Comment: "A large donkey-error America" -- I like it, Ophiuroid :-)

Comment: The Russian czar once wrote "Pardon not, to Siberia", and his minister who knew that the czar was weak on punctuation corrected him: "Pardon, not to Siberia".

Comment: @Ralph: never heard of that one, and a few quick Google/Yandex/Rambler searches do not return anything useful. There is, however, a similar (and extremely common) phrase that is used to teach Russian children punctuation: *казнить нельзя помиловать*. Depending on where you place the comma, you either get *казнить, нельзя помиловать* ("execute, do not pardon") or *казнить нельзя, помиловать* ("execute do not, pardon"). Anyhow, I am not aware of any actual czar ever writing that, only czars in Soviet-era fairy-tale movies do it every now and then.

Comment: @regDwight - Si non è vero, è ben trovato. I heard it in German, and it might well go back to the phrase you know.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There should be a hyphen between *big* and *ass*, as the two words together form an adjective, applied to *mistake*. (See also Ophiuroid’s comment referring to xkcd).

There should certainly be something before *America*; I agree with Boofus’s answer on that issue.

Answer (score 12):

How it should be punctuated depends on the message.  If one is telling America that it has made a big ass mistake, it should have the comma.  If one is saying that America *is* one big ass mistake (perhaps one is British), a colon would probably be best.

> One big ass mistake: America.

Comment: Perhaps if one were British, one might spell it 'arse'.

Comment: @Brian Hooper: One likely would.  Does anyone else spell it "ass" or is it only Americans?  Does anyone know a website where I could ask that?

Comment: is donkey synonymous with arse? Arse has ass' component of the buttocks, but not the donkey. Would not "ass" be a wholly separate word?

Comment: The context of the question was its meaning as buttocks.  I don't believe anyone uses "arse" to mean a donkey (though this site has taught me not to be sure about any of my beliefs about usage).

Answer (score 0):

If you're addressing America, the comma before the name is necessary.