# Is there a difference between “arse” and “ass”?

Tags: etymology, differences, british-english, offensive-language, north-american-english

[From a comment here,](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/4241/549) in frequent usage, *arse* and *ass* are often interchangeable when used to refer to buttocks or to a person of dubious charms. However, although “to arse about” has a vague connection to “make an ass of oneself”, many of the threads of meaning derived [from arse are not present in ass](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/arse). Likewise, ass has a donkey-referring component that arse does not.

Despite common perception, are these words more deviant than common usage indicates?

**Edit**: It appears they have (someone look this up with an authoritative dictionary please) different origins, *asinus* (Latin) for ass, and *ærs* (Old English) or *orros* (Greek) for arse.

Comment: Not entirely relevant, but I once had an email of mine rejected by a PC "profanity checker" for using the word "butt" as in "the butt of the joke".  I found that changing "butt" to "arse" made it apparently more acceptable.

Comment: @tony but was spelling checker screaming at you?

Comment: A small correction: asinus is Latin, not Greek.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Rather than getting confused, let me post an answer:

- In both British and American English, the word "ass" is used for "donkey".
- For "buttocks", British English uses "arse", while American English uses "ass".
- In British English, the two words are *not interchangeable*. "Arse" means only "buttocks", while "ass" means only "donkey".
- In American English, there is only one word, "ass", so the question of interchangeability does not arise.
- The idiom about "making an ass of oneself" is present in both varieties and refers to the "donkey" sense. (Also, "don't be an ass", etc.) Unrelated to this, there is "arse about" in British English, but no "ass about" in American English.
- Usage: The word "ass" is in practice less acceptable in American English than in British English, even when referring to donkeys, because of its other sense, considered vulgar.
  (Aside: A similar but different situation occurs with "cock", sometimes considered vulgar in American English which prefers "rooster" for one of its senses. The British phrase "cock up" is not used in American English.)

Comment: Vulgarity does not explain the distribution.  We do, for example, say "fuck up" in American English; that is, we have plenty of obscene or offensive idioms.  It's not that "cock up" is used more rarely in American English — it is simply nonexistent here.  Another example of the reverse situation: in US English we do not say "take the piss" to mean "make fun", even though "piss" is the same in British and American English.

Comment: @Kosmonaut: Thanks, that's an interesting point. I wonder if it's true in general that British English has more idioms using mildly vulgar words (cock up, arse about, take the piss…) (Though there's nothing vulgar about "cock up".)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR, "arse about" as in "arse about face"? :)

Comment: It's probably worth pointing out that ass although an americanism is being used increasingly by british people

Comment: @Shree: My intention was to say that there are probably just as many idioms with varying degrees of vulgarity in US English as British English.  I never wanted to make it sound like British English has a greater number of mildly vulgar words.

Comment: @Will but ultimately is it fair to consider "ass" an Americanism? That's the essence of this question. According to my notes (which are *not authoritative* AFAIK) on etymologies they have divergent origins.

Comment: @mfg I meant only when referring to an 'arse'

Comment: @will oh... interesting

Comment: @mfg I think we got a bit mixed up here. I was specifically commenting on "In British English, the two words are not interchangeable" just to say that in common usage this probably isn't really true

Comment: @ShreevastaR Man awesome!!Where did u learn all of this? i doubt even native speakers know this much.Kudos to you.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR - don't they say asshole (offense) in Britain? Or is it "arsehole"?

Comment: Wait, we don't use cock up on this side of the pond? That may be why those arseholes around me don't get it ...

Comment: In British English, even in Elizabethan times, the words *ass* and *arse* were close enough that Shakespeare used them in a pun; in *Midsummer Night's Dream*, the character Bottom is turned into an ass.

Comment: I disagree the assertion *"The word is less acceptable than in British English"*. It's my opinion that collectively, the British consider their **arse** to be far less socially acceptable than the equivalent American attitude to their **ass**.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I agree. On rereading the answer, I realise I wasn't clear: what I meant was that *ass* in American English (even when referring to donkeys) is less acceptable than *ass* in British English, for the obvious reason that it has a vulgar secondary meaning as well.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: Even after your edit, I don't see you've accurately described the difference. You virtually *never* see ["nice piece of arse"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22nice+piece+of+arse%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), because that's BrE spelling, and we would see it as really crude. Brits do actually use *"Nice piece of ass"* sometimes, but invariably written like that, and often pronounced with a short "a" (even by those who'd normally use the long form) to underline the distinction. *Ass/arse* are almost perceived as two different words by many Brits.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Yes I agree with all that; what parts of my answer contradict that? The "nice piece of arse" phrase is in Tony Andrews's answer; I made no reference to it. :) I already say in my answer, with emphasis, that "In British English, the two words are not interchangeable" -- they are two distinct words.

Answer (score 4):

I think that there is also a difference in "feel" between the British English word "arse" and the American English word "ass" in its "buttocks" sense.  The British version is vulgar but does not have the sexual overtones of the American version.  No British man would never describe a desirable woman as a "nice piece of arse" (I hope).

Comment: Sorry Tony. I'm pretty sure that some British men would. Especially ones who went to private school.

Answer (score 3):

*Arse* is the British word, and *ass* is the American/Canadian word.  Idioms formed from *arse* are going to be British idioms, while idioms formed with *ass* (referring to buttocks) are American/Canadian.  The dictionary entry you link to says "arse or ( US ), ( Canadian ) ass".  So, these words don't often overlap in usage.

Comment: If the only difference is in the regional spelling of the word why the differences in usage? Also, is 'arse' a word used to refer to a donkey? In the US you will hear 'ass' used in reference to a donkey matter-of-factly without vulgarity, whereas socially it is always vulgar. According to the definition, 'arse' is not vulgar and has no donkey usage in the UK. Is that part not accurate?

Comment: Thanks for referring me back to the dictionary, I hadn't checked the etymology; it appears they have (someone look this up with an authoritative dictionary please) different origins, *asinus* (Greek) for ass and *ærs* (Old English) or *orros* (Greek) for arse.

Comment: "Idioms formed from arse are going to be British idioms, while idioms formed with ass are American/Canadian" — I disagree. "Making an ass of oneself" is both British and American, and has to do with donkeys, and is unrelated to buttocks.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: "These words don't *often* overlap in usage".  Certainly there are shared idioms between British and American English.

Comment: @Shree I think my question arose mostly because **donkey is not listed** in the usage of 'arse' (except by Ask.com's linkage). It *also* arose because of Boofus' comment about spelling being the only difference; as if the American 'ass' was interchangeable with the British 'arse.'

Comment: @mfg, I get the impression from your comments that you believe that "ass" and "arse" are pronounced the same. In UK English this is definitely NOT the case. (I don't know for US English.)

Comment: @ben I would have to say that due to lack of hearing Brits that I've known pronounce the R that I've taken for granted a similarity; but most Americans I assume do pronounce the R, likely due to only seeing arse.

Answer (score 3):

In British English (I'm English, although that's no qualification!) it would appear that whether something is or is not rude depends not only on context regarding the subject but also phraseology. *Ass* vs. *arse* is a regional and also potentially a class distinction.

- *You cock* — very rude
- *Cock up* — not really that rude
- *You complete arse* — rude
- [*Arse over tit/tip*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/go-arse-over-tit-tip) - quite rude
- *Make an arse of myself* — (yes we do say that)
- *You silly arse* — (this is strangely not rude at all)
- *Arse end* — slightly rude.

To confuse things further we might also call someone a 'donkey' which isn't always too offensive, usually when they have done something stupid rather than clumsy.

There is a strong regional difference too with people of the north using *ass* and the south using *arse*. This follows similar lines to pronunciation of *bath* etc. with northerners using a short 'a' à la *ass* and southerners using a long 'a' as in *arse*.

Answer (score 2):

*Ass* and *arse* are completely separate words. I believe the version of *ass* meaning *bottom* is nothing more than an americanised pronunciation of *arse*, and then a suitable spelling thereof.

When Northerners, or anyone, says *silly ass!*, I think they mean a donkey, not an arse.

Brit speakers always pronounce *ass* (donkey) with a short initial vowel but they increasingly use *ass* (arse) in the Am sense and pronounce it with a long vowel to mark the difference. Do americans mark the two versions of *ass* by varying the pronunciation? I think they use a long vowel in both cases.

Comment: How can you tell if a British speaker is pronouncing *arse* without the 'r' or pronouncing *ass* with a long vowel? Don't they sound the same?. Americans use a short vowel for both words.

Comment: You're partly right. "Ass" meaning bottom, is American dialect for arse. As for using ass in the American sense, I haven't heard British people do that. If it happens, it must be rare and limited to a few people.

Comment: Peter Shor. Ass and arse sound distinctively different, in the UK, whatever British accent they are spoken in.

Comment: @Tristan: I think what Barry means is that people are dropping the 'r' in *arse* when speaking rhotic dialects (since it seems he's a Northerner). It now sounds just the same as somebody speaking a non-rhotic dialect, which is still different from *ass*.

Comment: What do you mean, Peter? Ass and arse sound distinctively different, even when non-rhotic. Maybe this is hard to notice for Americans who are not used to non-rhotic speech.

Comment: @Tristan: I understand that *ass* and *arse* are different even without the 'r'. What I don't understand is Barry's comment *"Brits pronounce ass (donkey) with a short vowel but they increasingly use ass (arse) in the American sense and pronounce it with a long vowel to mark the difference."* Wouldn't *ass* pronounced with a long vowel rhyme with RP *glass,* and be pronounced exactly the same as *arse* with a dropped 'r'?

Comment: I see what you mean. Yes. That point about a long vowel, from Barry, was confusing.

Answer (score -1):

British people began calling the animal a donkey around 200 years ago to avoid potential confusion between 'ass' and 'arse'.

Comment: before someone else says it. Please provide references to support your answer. Thanks.

Comment: And before someone else mentions it, six years ago referenced answers were not seen as a necessity hence none of the answers before yours provided support. [**ass n.2** slang for "backside," **first attested 1860** in nautical slang, **in popular use from 1930**;](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=ass&allowed_in_frame=0)

Comment: [**donkey** 1785, originally slang... The older English word was **ass n.1**](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=donkey)